# After decompile apk why class names and object are letter

Tags: java, android, encryption, decompiling

I'm trying to learn new android methods.Before I develop new android application, I'm searching published applications.

If I decompile my application's apk, class names and objects names remains same

But If I decompile application that is in market, class and object names contains letter. That is why I don't understand what programmer did in code.
Do they encrypt the code?
any way to decrypt it?

Comment: yes SIr, to point you in the right direction, google something called `proguard` start here on stackoverflow, and you will find all the answers and question your brain want to ask in 4 minutes..

Comment: if your intention is to learn the programming, you should read book or manual website. IMHO decompiling and checking out someone's code seems to steal the business logic.

Answer (score 3):

The apks were probably obfuscated with [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). If it's your app, disable obfuscation.

As for why apps on the market do it, it's so you can't do what you're doing now and decompile to (coherent) source. As far as I know there is no way around it, and it would be unethical to try do so. We're software developers here, so we won't help you take another developers work from them.

Answer (score 1):

They *obfuscated* the code. Obfuscation is an automatic process which renames all classes/methods/fields with short sequential names, removes unused classes/methods/fields, and sometimes encrypts strings.

There is no easy way to deobfuscate the code.

Comment: @Beyaz decompile it as normal, then manually rename everything.